# Polymer neon-animations example not animating

Tags: polymer

So I have take the example neon-animation code found here http://morethanreal.github.io/neon-animation-demo/bower_components/neon-animation/demo/declarative/index.html

And copied it into my c9.io IDE environment to see if I can get it to work without changes other than it working in my environment. I can't.

**The code I am running does not animate the way the above example does. Pages change, but they do not slide left and right. They just change.**

The copy of the code is below, noting that they only real change I made to the example code are import statements to point at my own repository, plus a few console logs.

I am presuming I have a version issue with my Polymer installed code. But I note that the polymer files do not record their version number. I used bower to install #^1.0.0; although I did get "Unable to find a suitable version" errors and had to resolve those.

Looking at my version of Polymer code and comparing it to that used by the original example code I can tell that some are different, but with the deep number of imports going on its not practical to follow all the important statements and find all the differences.

Is there are way to determine versions? Is there are way to verify what I am running? Any suggestions welcome?

```
        <head>
          <title>neon-animated-pages demo: declarative</title>

          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">

          <script src="bower_components//webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
          </script>
          <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
          <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animated-pages.html">
          <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animatable.html">
          <link rel="import" href="bower_components/neon-animation/neon-animations.html">

          <style>
            .toolbar {
              padding: 8px;
            }
          </style>

          <style is="custom-style">
            neon-animatable {
              color: white;
              @apply(--layout-horizontal);
              @apply(--layout-center-center);
              @apply(--paper-font-display4);
            }

            neon-animatable:nth-child(1) {
              background: var(--paper-red-500);
            }

            neon-animatable:nth-child(2) {
              background: var(--paper-blue-500);
            }

            neon-animatable:nth-child(3) {
              background: var(--paper-orange-500);
            }

            neon-animatable:nth-child(4) {
              background: var(--paper-green-500);
            }

            neon-animatable:nth-child(5) {
              background: var(--paper-purple-500);
            }
          </style>

        </head>

        <body class="fullbleed layout vertical">

          <template is="dom-bind">

            <div class="toolbar">
              <button on-click="_onPrevClick">&lt;&lt;</button>
              <button on-click="_onNextClick">&gt;&gt;</button>
            </div>

            <neon-animated-pages id="pages" class="flex" selected="[[selected]]" entry-animation="[[entryAnimation]]" exit-animation="[[exitAnimation]]">
              <neon-animatable>1</neon-animatable>
              <neon-animatable>2</neon-animatable>
              <neon-animatable>3</neon-animatable>
              <neon-animatable>4</neon-animatable>
              <neon-animatable>5</neon-animatable>
            </neon-animated-pages>

          </template>

          <script>
            this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-left-animation';
            this.exitAnimation = 'slide-right-animation';
            var scope = document.querySelector('template[is="dom-bind"]');
            scope.selected = 0;

            scope._onPrevClick = function() {
              console.log()
              this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-left-animation';
              this.exitAnimation = 'slide-right-animation';
              console.log(pages.entryAnimation);
              this.selected = this.selected === 0 ? 4 : (this.selected - 1);
            }

            scope._onNextClick = function() {
              this.entryAnimation = 'slide-from-right-animation';
              this.exitAnimation = 'slide-left-animation';
              console.log(pages.exitAnimation);
              this.selected = this.selected === 4 ? 0 : (this.selected + 1);
            }
          </script>

        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct. [Here](http://jsbin.com/ligihekewu/edit?html,output) is a dump of your code into JSBin and it works.

`neon-animation` implements `web-animations-js` - perhaps you installed v2.1.1 which [breaks](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation/issues/51) `neon-animation`. You can check versions by looking at the `.bower.json` file in your `bower_components/<element-name>` directory.

Update your components and you should be fine. I haven't had problems when I set my bower dependencies to something like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.0.0",
    "layout": "Polymer/layout",
    "iron-elements": "PolymerElements/iron-elements#^1.0.0",
    "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.0",
    "gold-elements": "PolymerElements/gold-elements#^1.0.0",
    "platinum-elements": "PolymerElements/platinum-elements#^1.0.0",
    "neon-elements": "PolymerElements/neon-animation#^1.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: What I found interesting about my own `bower.json` file is it lacks a reference to neon.    

`
     "dependencies": {
            "core-elements": "Polymer/core-elements#^0.5.6",
            "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^0.5.6",
            "core-icon": "Polymer/core-icon#~0.5.6",
            "core-icons": "Polymer/core-icons#~0.5.6",
            "paper-elements": "PolymerElements/paper-elements#^1.0.0",
            "paper-material": "PolymerElements/paper-material#^1.0.0"
          },
`

Comment: You seem to be mixing Polymer 0.5+ stuff with 1.0+? They are incompatible. I will start fresh and place the dependencies I've listed above in `bower.json` and try again.

Comment: Yes. I think you are right. I note you use PolymerElements. I think I installed Polymer#^1.0.0 which struggled to installed only 1.0.0. And I had to resolve it to other versions. I will try again.

Comment: Well that was easy. I did a 'bower update' and it brought my versions up to date. Thanks for your help @zeroevx